# In Tailwind CSS, container class max-width is not working in sm device

Tags: tailwind-css

In Tailwind CSS, when we use the container class, it should take the maxwidth of 640px in sm device.But it is not working for the sm.For the rest of the breakpoint classes maxwidth is working correctly in Google chrome